# jQuery sortable 'display as a grid' order

Tags: jquery, css

Based on the example jQuery sortable 'display as a grid' found at http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid

The < li > elements are displayed as follow using css

```
1  2  3  4 
5  6  7  8 
9 10 11 12
```

Is there a way to have them ordered as

```
1  4  7  10
2  5  8  11
3  6  9  12
```

And therefore having the sorting to behave 'by column'? For instance, dragging 10 to 7 would push 7 to where 8 is, 8 to 9, 9 to 10 and 11, and 12 would stay the same.

Comment: [Tablesorter.js](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) is nice for sorting but you'll have to use `<table>` (and do some manual work to pivot data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the `ul`, add styling

```
ul#sortable {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

The `height` can be change depending on how many rows you want.

The down-side is support for `flex` is IE +10.0

https://css-tricks.com/arranging-elements-top-bottom-instead-left-right-float/

**Edit**

Adding some extra flex instructions (e.g. `-webkit-flex`) solved it for safari (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-direction.asp):

```
ul#sortable {
  height: 300px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction:column;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap; 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: `flex-direction` and `flex-wrap` aren't reliable codes, these just gets support IE +11.0

Comment: @Sajad, IE +10.0, I will update my answer to mention that. Thanks